# Why client.GetUserDialogsAsync() throws error couldn't read packet length in TLSharp

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await, telegram

I have a wpf app that uses 2 different telegram accounts to send same messages to different groups and channels. It works perfect in 90 percent of executions and fails in 10 percent. I mean that first account reads and sends its messages but in 10 percent of executions second account fails with the couldn't read packet length error.
here is line of my code that throws error:

```
for (int k = 1; k < clients.Length; k++)
{
    tldialogs[k] =  clients[k].client.GetUserDialogsAsync().Result as TLDialogs;
    ...
}
```

please if you know anything about it tell me and help to finish this headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
var dialogs = (TLDialogs) await client.GetUserDialogsAsync();
```